# Updating SQL Server 2008 R2 using slipstreamed source

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to create a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 setup media. I have done this using slipstream method as recommended by Microsoft. I can only use this to create new installation. But is there a way I can use this media to update an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an existing instance just apply the service pack, if you want to do this without user interaction, do the following:

unpack the downloaded package:

```
SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe -x
```

then start the service pack installation with parameters like:

```
setup.exe /quiet /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /indicateprogress
```